# SwiftUI initialization of app not working

Tags: swiftui, initialization

I am trying to run a function on initiation in SwiftUI, but it doesn't seem to be working.

```
import SwiftUI

@main
struct ExampleApp: App {
    init() {
        print("app initiated")
    }
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            AppContentView().onAppear {
                print("ContentView appeared!")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It only prints once the app has been ran on the simulator and opened for the first time. Why is it not working?

Comment: "Downloaded"? You mean it's actually in the App Store? Or does downloaded mean run from Xcode on your device? Seems like we're missing some details here.

Comment: Good point. Edited right now.

Comment: When I run that code, the `init` runs when the app is launched. The other `print` runs when the content view first appears. Neither of those things really happen again, so they just run once. This, as far as I can tell, is expected behavior. What are you expecting to see happen that isn't?

Comment: I want it to work whenever I open the app, not just when it is first uploaded.

Comment: Maybe you're looking for `.onChange(of: scenePhase) { newScenePhase` to look for when the app becomes active from the background?

Comment: @jnpdx Where do I put that?

Comment: https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-detect-when-your-app-moves-to-the-background-or-foreground-with-scenephase

Comment: That doesn't seem to work, it only works when I exit the app. My goal here is whenever the app is opened from being completely inactive, a function should run.

Comment: I can't replicate that on my end. The code that I linked to works fine, at least on iOS 14.5. What is your setup?