# SwiftUI AppDelegate not being ran whenever app is opened

Tags: swiftui, appdelegate

Here is a simple `AppDelegate` that I have made:

```swift
import SwiftUI

class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    private func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: NSDictionary?) -> Bool {
        print("application")
        // first launch
        // this method is called only on first launch when app was closed / killed
        return true
    }

    private func applicationWillEnterForeground(application: UIApplication) -> Bool{
        print("applicationWillEnterForeground")
        // app will enter in foreground
        // this method is called on first launch when app was closed / killed and every time app is reopened or change status from background to foreground (ex. mobile call)
        return true
    }

    private func applicationDidBecomeActive(application: UIApplication) -> Bool {
        print("applicationDidBecomeActive")
        // app becomes active
        // this method is called on first launch when app was closed / killed and every time app is reopened or change status from background to foreground (ex. mobile call)
        return true
    }
}

@main
struct CouponDeckApp: App {
    @UIApplicationDelegateAdaptor(AppDelegate.self) var appDelegate
    @Environment(\.scenePhase) private var scenePhase
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            AppContentView()
                
        }
    }
}
```

The `AppDelegate` doesn't seem to be calling any of its functions, though. It should be running them at 3 places, but none are running. Why is this happening, and how do I fix it?

Comment: In the SwiftUI lifecycle, the `applicationWillEnterForeground` and `applicationDidBecomeActive` don't seem to get called (however, you also don't have the correct method signatures for them -- use autocomplete to see what they actually should be). @swiftPunk already gave you an answer on one of your questions asking the same thing showing you how to do this in SwiftUI. I also linked to this information for you when you first asked here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68716601/swiftui-initialization-of-app-not-working

Comment: It seems you are missing some point! you are asking same question in deferent forms!

Comment: @jnpdx in the Apple Documentation, I seem to be correct. The names match perfectly.

Comment: @swiftPunk that's because none of the answers anyone has given to me have worked.

Comment: @KunalKatiyar no, they don't. Check the return types.

Comment: @jnpdx even by removing the return types, it still doesn't work.

Comment: I already said that those methods don’t work in the SwiftUI lifecycle. @swiftPunk and I have both shown you how to do this in SwiftUI

Comment: I feel your pain jnpdx

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You've marked your app with `@main` which makes it app entry point.

Not all methods of app delegate will work with `UIApplicationDelegateAdaptor`, like here `applicationWillEnterForeground` `applicationDidBecomeActive` won't be called.

Instead you're supposed to use publishers inside SwiftUI view, like this:

```
.onReceive(NotificationCenter.default.publisher(for: UIApplication.didBecomeActiveNotification)) { _ in
    print("applicationDidBecomeActive")
}
.onReceive(NotificationCenter.default.publisher(for: UIApplication.willEnterForegroundNotification)) { _ in
    print("applicationWillEnterForeground")
}
```

An other problem with your `AppDelegate` is that it doesn't have needed methods signature. When you're adding new method, don't paste it from somewhere, instead type a couple of letters from method name and let Xcode finish the rest. In your case if you have your signature correct, `private` would be an error reported by Xcode.

If you still wanna get them inside your delegate for some reason, you need to move `@main` to `AppDelegate`, and initialize your SwiftUI view with `UIHostingController` like it was back done in SwiftUI 1:

```
@main
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?
    
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        let window = UIWindow()
        self.window = window
        window.rootViewController = UIHostingController(rootView: ContentView())
        window.makeKeyAndVisible()
        return true
    }
    
    func applicationWillEnterForeground(_ application: UIApplication) {
        print("applicationWillEnterForeground")
    }
    
    func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
        print("applicationDidBecomeActive")
    }
}
```

Also you need to update `Info.plist`, set enable multiple windows to `NO`:

[image]

Comment: How do you edit the Info.plist file like that? Also, on every example I've seen, people can use `AppDelegate` and `App` together using `UIApplicationDelegateAdaptor` .

Comment: @KunalKatiyar I was not particularly correct about `UIApplicationDelegateAdaptor`, check out updated answer

Comment: It probably works, but the real problem (as pointed out in one of my other questions) is that `print` statements don't work the second time! When I ran another function that actually edits stuff, it worked perfectly! But I'll accept your answer because it technically works.

Comment: Had to upvote for the nice tips that were included. Thank-you.

Answer (score 1):

Use the SceneDelegate file instead.

Add it in this method:

```
func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) { }
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, if you are using SceneDelegate in your project, you can implement the equivalent methods:

```swift
func sceneDidBecomeActive(_ scene: UIScene) {

}

func sceneWillEnterForeground(_ scene: UIScene) {

}
```